# Generate dynamic links firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Am currently developing an Invoice app that lets a user create an invoice and share. I want to make it such that when they create it, a link is generated with query parameters being the user id and invoice id. I also want that when a link of that type(for example https://invoiceapp.com/userId+invoiceId) is clicked, it opens up in the app and I get the invoice id and user id. Please help out

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio

Select Tools > App Links Assistant.
Click Open URL Mapping Editor and then click Add at the bottom of the URL Mapping list to add a new URL mapping.
Add details for the new URL mapping

Once you've verified that your URL mapping is working correctly, add logic to handle the intent you created.

Click Select Activity from the App Links Assistant.
Select an activity from the list and click Insert Code.

After setting up URL support for your app, the App Links Assistant generates a Digital Asset Links file you can use to associate your website with your app.
To associate your app and your website using the App Links Assistant, click Open the Digital Asset Links File Generator